# Conditional pipeline

Tags: shell-script, shell, pipe

Say I've got the following pipeline:

```
cmd1 < input.txt |\
cmd2 |\
cmd4 |\
cmd5 |\
cmd6 |\
(...) |\
cmdN > result.txt
```

Under certain conditions I would like to add a `cmd3` between `cmd2` and `cmd4`. Is there a way to create a kind of conditional pipeline without saving the result of `cmd2` into a temporary file? I would think of something like:

```
cmd1 < input.txt |\
cmd2 |\
(${DEFINED}? cmd3 : cat ) |\
cmd4 |\
cmd5 |\
cmd6 |\
(...) |\
cmdN > result.txt
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520085/how-do-i-conditionally-redirect-the-output-of-a-command-to-dev-null

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just the usual `&&` and `||` operators:

```sh
cmd1 < input.txt |
cmd2 |
( [ -n "$DEFINED" ] && cmd3 || cat ) |
cmd4 |
cmd5 |
cmd6 |
(...) |
cmdN > result.txt
```

Although, as specified by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38312/160697), you would generally prefer `if ... else`, if you're after the if-else syntax:

```sh
  ...
  cmd2 |
  if [ -n "$DEFINED" ]; then cmd3; else cat; fi |
  cmd4 |
  ...
```

(Note that no trailing backslash is needed when the line ends with pipe.)

**Update** according to [Jonas' observation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39043).
If cmd3 may terminate with non-zero exit code and you not want `cat` to process the remaining input, reverse the logic:

```sh
cmd1 < input.txt |
cmd2 |
( [ -z "$DEFINED" ] && cat || cmd3 ) |
cmd4 |
cmd5 |
cmd6 |
(...) |
cmdN > result.txt
```

Comment: Handy tip Noted!

Comment: Be aware of the gotchas: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39043/19055

Comment: Reversing the logic doesn't help. If `cat` returns with a non-zero exit status (common when getting a SIGPIPE), then `cmd3` will be run. Better use if/then/else as in [Thor's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38312/22565) or other solutions that avoid running `cat`.

Comment: so cat can be used to connect things, kind of like a "through" stream

Answer (score 29):

`if`/`else`/`fi` works. Assuming any Bourne-like shell:

```
cmd1 < input.txt |
cmd2 |
if [ -n "$DEFINED" ]; then cmd3; else cat; fi |
cmd4 |
cmd5 |
cmd6 |
(...) |
cmdN > result.txt
```

Answer (score 15):

All the answers given so far replace `cmd3` with `cat`. You can also avoid running any command with:

```
if [ -n "$DEFINE" ]; then
  alias maybe_cmd3='cmd3 |'
else
  alias maybe_cmd3=''
fi
cmd1 |
cmd2 |
maybe_cmd3
cmd4 |
... |
cmdN > result.txt
```

That's POSIX, but note that if in a `bash` script where `bash` is not in `sh`-mode (like with a script starting with `#! /path/to/bash -`), you'll need to enable alias expansion with `shopt -s expand_aliases` (or `set -o posix`).

Another approach that still doesn't run any unnecessary command is to use eval:

```
if [ -n "$DEFINE" ]; then
  maybe_cmd3='cmd3 |'
else
  maybe_cmd3=''
fi
eval "
  cmd1 |
  cmd2 |
  $maybe_cmd3
  cmd4 |
  ... |
  cmdN > result.txt"
```

Or:

```
eval "
  cmd1 |
  cmd2 |
  ${DEFINE:+cmd3 |}
  cmd4 |
  ... |
  cmdN > result.txt"
```

On Linux (at least), instead of `cat`, you could use `pv -q` which uses `splice()` instead of `read()` + `write()` to pass the data across between the two pipes which avoids having the data moved twice between kernel and user space.

Another option could be to define a function that runs a give command piped to or from `cmd3` or not depending on `$DEFINE`.

```
if [ -n "$DEFINE" ]; then
  maybe_preprocess_with_cmd3() { cmd3 | "$@"; }
  maybe_postprocess_with_cmd3() { "$@" | cmd3; }
else
  maybe_preprocess_with_cmd3() { "$@"; }
  maybe_postprocess_with_cmd3() { "$@"; }
fi
```

And then:

```
cmd1 |
cmd2 |
maybe_preprocess_with_cmd3 cmd4 |
... |
cmdN > result.txt
```

Or:

```
cmd1 |
maybe_postprocess_with_cmd3 cmd2 |
cmd4 |
... |
cmdN > result.txt
```

Answer (score 12):

As an addendum to [manatwork's accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38311/19055): be aware of the and-false-or gotcha and its interaction with streams.  For instance,

```
true && false || echo foo
```

outputs `foo`.  Not surprisingly,

```
true && (echo foo | grep bar) || echo baz
```

and

```
echo foo | (true && grep bar || echo baz)
```

both output `baz`.  (Note that `echo foo | grep bar` is false and has no output).  However,

```
echo foo | (true && grep bar || sed -e abaz)
```

outputs nothing.  This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: I can't see how is this relevant here. The `else` (or `||`) should act as a null operation keeping the input unchanged. So replacing `cat` with `echo` changes everything making your code irrelevant. Regarding the “and-false-or gotcha”, I see no interference with the pipeline: http://pastebin.com/u6Jq0bZe

Comment: @manatwork: One thing Jonas is pointing out is that, in `[[ "${DEFINED}" ]] && cmd3 || cat`, `cmd3` and `cat` are not the mutually exclusive `then` and `else` branches of the same `if`, but that if `cmd3` fails, then `cat` will also be executed. (Of course, if `cmd3` always succeeds, or if it consumes all the input so there's nothing left in `stdin` for `cat` to process, then the it may not matter.) If you need both `then` and `else` branches, it's better to use an explicit `if` command, not `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, @musiphil. Now I understand Jonas' argument.

Comment: Main takeaway is that `condition && command1 || command2` is **not** the same as `if condition; then command1; else command2; fi`

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar situation that I solved with bash *functions*:

```
if ...; then
  my_cmd3() { cmd3; }
else
  my_cmd3() { cat; }
if

cmd1 < input.txt |
cmd2 |
my_cmd3 |
cmd4 |
cmd5 |
cmd6 |
(...) |
cmdN > result.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative possible solution:
concatenating named pipes in order to create a pseudo-pipeline:

```
dir="$(mktemp -d)"
addfifo() {
  stdin="$dir/$fifo_n"
  [ "$1" ] || mkfifo "$dir/$((fifo_n=fifo_n+1))"
  stdout="$dir/$fifo_n"
}

addfifo; echo "The slow pink fox crawl under the brilliant dog" > "$stdout" &

# Restoring the famous line: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
# just replace 'true' with 'false' in any of the 5 following lines and the pseudo-pipeline will still work
true && { addfifo; sed 's/brilliant/lazy/' < "$stdin" > "$stdout" & }
true && { addfifo; sed 's/under/over/'     < "$stdin" > "$stdout" & }
true && { addfifo; sed 's/crawl/jumps/'    < "$stdin" > "$stdout" & }
true && { addfifo; sed 's/pink/brown/'     < "$stdin" > "$stdout" & }
true && { addfifo; sed 's/slow/quick/'     < "$stdin" > "$stdout" & }

addfifo -last; cat < "$stdin"

wait; rm -r "$dir"
```

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, if you are coming here looking for conditional pipes in **fish**, this is how you do it:

```
set -l flags "yes"
# ... 
echo "conditionalpipeline" | \
  if contains -- "yes" $flags 
    sed "s/lp/l p/"
  else
    cat
  end | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```