# How can I append a command

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, tail, head

I can't remember how to append a command to a shell script. I searched for *append*, *add*, *concat*, and more without success.

Basically I have

```
belly = tail -n +"$HEAD" "$1" | head -n $((TAIL-HEAD+1))

if [ -z "${NUMBER+x}" ]; then # check if NUMBER exists
    tail -n +"$HEAD" "$1" | head -n $((TAIL-HEAD+1))
else
    tail -n +"$HEAD" "$1" | head -n $((TAIL-HEAD+1)) | cat -n
fi
```

and it works fine, but I don't like the duplicate logic. I know that I could use a function or eval, but is there a simpler way to do this? In my head I have something like this:

```
belly = tail -n +$HEAD $1 | head -n $((TAIL-HEAD+1))

if [ -z "${NUMBER+x}" ]; then # check if NUMBER exists
    belly
else
    belly | cat -n
fi
```

But it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: @Cyrus done. This website rocks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this may have been answered here: [Conditional pipeline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38310/conditional-pipeline)

That answer takes the shell `if/then/else` mechanic and uses it to embed logic *inside* pipeline. You can do that also with the `&&` operator, but it is not so clean to read, so I prefer `if`.

Basically in your case the `tail` line would be like so (please note also the change of `-z` to `-n`):

```
tail -n +"$HEAD" "$1" |
head -n $((TAIL-HEAD+1)) |
if [ -n "${NUMBER+x}" ]; then cat -n; else cat; fi
```

(this may have some errors, I'm not so keen on Linux shell programming. But you get the point.)

Comment: You don't need to put the conditional in a subshell, just `something | if ... fi ` works. But you __do__ need an else branch, and a cat again, since otherwise the subshell/if-statement just eats up all input, if the condition isn't true. Try `echo foo |  if false ; then cat -n ; fi`

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you want accomplished is to pass or not to pass the `-n` option to `cat` depending on the state of `$NUMBER`

Just do this:

```
tail -n +"$HEAD" "$1" | head -n $((TAIL-HEAD+1)) | cat ${NUMBER:+'-n'}
```

We can do away with the UUOC scenario as well:

```
eval "tail -n +\"$HEAD\" \"\$1\" | head -n \$((TAIL-HEAD+1)) ${NUMBER:+|cat -n}"
```

Comment: Clever. Is the useless call to `cat` is troublesome?

Comment: @aloisdg This is not a case of UUOC. Just look at the complexity involved in doing away with the lone `cat`, IMHO not worth it.

Comment: @aloisdg, it's an extra process and an extra step of copying data, but if you that starts to matter performance-wise, you shouldn't be using a three-command pipeline to begin with, but something like awk or perl instead.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to set a variable to manage the changing part of the pipeline. If the only changing part is a command line parameter, the implementation is simple:

```
cat_arg=""
if [ -n "${NUMBER+x}" ]; then
    cat_arg="-n"
fi    
somepipeline ... | cat $cat_arg
```

Though this way, it's hard to completely remove the last part of the pipeline, so we'll uselessly use a cat, but that's not likely to matter much. Also, this depends on *not* quoting the variable, which makes it impossible to use whitespace or glob characters within the changing arguments.

So an array would be better:

```
final=(cat) 
if [ -n "${NUMBER+x}" ]; then
    final=(cat -n)
fi    
somepipeline ... | "${final[@]}"
```

Or you could create two functions and call one through a variable.

Incidentally, a shell function is also the answer to your other question.

```
# define the function
belly() {
    tail -n +"$HEAD" "$1" | head -n $((TAIL-HEAD+1))
}
if ... ; then
    belly "$1" | this
else 
    belly "$1" | that
fi
```

You need to pass `$1` explicitly since functions have their own context of positional parameters.